# How to overwrite Field name in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforce-id

How to overwrite the Field name in LWC.

For Example : in the below screen show i have field called `Family Name` in UI, I have to overwrite the field to `NAME`

I tried to add this code in JS `{ fieldAPI: 'Family_Name__c', required:true, **fieldName:'Name'** },` not worked. Please help me on this

[image]

**Html:**

```
<template for:each={familyName} for:item="field" for:index="index">
                            <div class={sectionLayout} key={field.fieldAPI}>
                                <lightning-input-field field-name={field.fieldAPI} required={field.required}>
                                </lightning-input-field>
                            </div>
                        </template>
```

**js:**

```
import { LightningElement, track } from "lwc";

export default class Enrollment extends LightningElement {
  @track enrollmentId;

 @track familyName = [
  { fieldAPI: 'Family_Name__c', required:true, fieldName:'Name' },
  { fieldAPI:'Home_Phone__c', required:true}
];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:-

```
<label for="fieldid">your custom label</label>
<lightning-input-field id="fieldid" field-name="Phone" variant="label-hidden">
</lightning-input-field>
```

You can hide the label using variant property and use your own custom label.

> The variant changes the label position of an input field. Accepted
>   variants include standard, label-hidden, label-inline, and
>   label-stacked. If variant is specified, the label position is
>   determined by the variant. Otherwise, it is determined by the density
>   setting of the parent form.

In your case to make it dynamic, You can do like this:-

```
<template for:each={familyName} for:item="field" for:index="index">
     <div class={sectionLayout} key={field.fieldAPI}>
          <label for={field.fieldAPI}>{field.fieldName}</label>
          <lightning-input-field id={field.fieldAPI} field-name={field.fieldAPI} required={field.required}>
          </lightning-input-field>
     </div>
</template>
```

Reference:- [Input Field](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input-field/specification)